# Backbone.js - Is my model is correct - in case of multiple level datas

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-relational

I am getting json data from server for make the navigation menu (has the sublinks ) - for that, i am making my model as follow. is this correct..? any one help me please?

Here is the json i am getting from server:

```
[
    {
        "label": "General",
        "link": "#/general",
        "subLinks": [
            {
                "label": "Dashboard",
                "link": "#/dashboard"
            },
            {
                "label": "My Task",
                "link": "#/mytask"
            },
            {
                "label": "My Documents",
                "link": "#/mydocuments"
            },
            {
                "label": "My Templates",
                "link": "#/mytemplates"
            },
            {
                "label": "Search",
                "link": "#/search"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "label": "Repositories",
        "link": "#/reposotories",
        "subLinks": []
    },
    {
        "label": "SavedSearches",
        "link": "#/savedSearches",
        "subLinks": []
    },
    {
        "label": "Favourites",
        "link": "#/favourites",
        "subLinks": []
    },
    {
        "label": "Reports",
        "link": "#/reports",
        "subLinks": []
    },
    {
        "label": "Preferences",
        "link": "#/preferences",
        "subLinks": []
    }
]
```

after i receive my json i use the parse method to manipulate the models:

```
 define(["backbone","models/model","collection/baseCollection"], function (Backbone,model,baseCollection) {

    var mainLinkModel = model.extend({
        defaults:{
            label:"mainLink",
            link:"#",
            subLinks:[
                          label:"mainLink",
                  link:"#"
                   ]
        }
    })

    var headerCollection = baseCollection.extend({
        url:function(){
            return this.path + "edms/navigationLinksTest"
        },
        model:model,
        initialize:function(){

        },
        parse:function(response){

            var mainNavi = [];

            _.each(response.navList, function(m){
                            // i am making new models.. but how to handle the sublinks?
                mainNavi.push(new mainLinkModel(m));
            })

        }
    });

    return new headerCollection;

})
```

how to handle this kind of models.. any one help me in this please..?

Comment: Can you paste in the response you are getting from the server? We need to make sure that the response returns "navList" or if there is still a level you need to go down before that information is available.

Comment: Exactly the same what i am getting from json, i paste above.